# Django 1.7 Migration Errors when deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-migrations

Python and Django newbie here. Part of my code is based on the video tutorial [Launch with Code](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzT5veidCTZ1mQriBX0Mu2LF) from [Coding for Entrepreneurs](https://codingforentrepreneurs.com/).

Using Python 2.7.5 with Django 1.7.4 and trying to deploy my app on Heroku, I get stuck with an error I don't understand when synchronizing the database.
I run:

`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

And I get the following error:

```
Running `python manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9158
    Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, admin, ppm, contenttypes
    Running migrations:
      Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
      Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
      Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
      Applying ppm.0001_initial... OK
      Applying ppm.0002_auto_20150131_1822... OK
      Applying ppm.0003_auto_20150131_2241... OK
      Applying ppm.0004_auto_20150131_2246... OK
      Applying ppm.0005_auto_20150131_2317... OK
      Applying ppm.0006_auto_20150201_0008... OK
      Applying ppm.0007_auto_20150201_0020... OK
      Applying ppm.0008_auto_20150201_0023... OK
      Applying ppm.0009_auto_20150201_0031... OK
      Applying ppm.0010_auto_20150201_0032... OK
      Applying ppm.0011_auto_20150201_0035... OK
      Applying ppm.0012_auto_20150201_0132... OK
      Applying ppm.0013_auto_20150201_0219... OK
      Applying ppm.0014_auto_20150201_0247...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
        self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
        migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
        schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 454, in alter_field
        self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 600, in _alter_field
        params,
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 102, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "username_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
    HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

I can't make sense of this error as I don't have any `username_id` in my ppm app models.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class SpielInput(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    spiel = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.user.username)

    def game(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.spiel)

class AnamneseInput(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    anamnese = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.user.username)

    def amn(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.anamnese)

class TherapieInput(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    therapie = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.user.username)

    def ther(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.therapie)
```

I have tried to destroy my Heroku app many times and changing my models.py but nothing worked. I guess I should make use of the `HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.` but I have no idea how.

**Edit 1: add file that triggered the error**

0014_auto_20150201_0247.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        dependencies = [
            ('ppm', '0013_auto_20150201_0219'),
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.AlterField(
                model_name='spielinput',
                name='username',
                field=models.ForeignKey(to='ppm.ProjectUser'),
                preserve_default=True,
            ),
        ]
```

The problem seems to be with `field=models.ForeignKey(to='ppm.ProjectUser'),`. `ProjectUser` used to be the table to save the users, but as I didn't need it, I deleted it when still working locally.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the file for the migration that triggered the error?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In `ppm/migrations` folder, there will be a file with the name `0014_auto_20150201_0247`; update your question with the contents of this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using Django 1.7 (with migrations included) whereas the tutorial I followed use Django 1.6 (using South to do migrations).

When working locally, I have changed my models.py many times and thus the database has changed many times as well, with every changes saved into my folder `ppm/migrations`.

So all I needed to do was to add all those migration change files into my .gitignore file. Thus, they are not taken into the production app on Heroku.

.gitignore:

```
ppm/migrations/0001_initial.py
[etc.]
ppm/migrations/0014_auto_20150201_0247.py
[etc.]
```

then run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Modified .gitignore"
git rm --cached ppm/migrations/00*
git commit -m "Removed migration files"
git push heroku app master
heroku run manage.py migrate
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended Django upgrade path is to delete your south migrations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

Comment: I did everything with Django 1.7 so I didn't need to upgrade from South. What I had not understood is that I had pushed (i.e. `git push`) my local migrations files on the Heroku server, which is what triggered the error. Thus my answer with modifying the .gitignore file.